Searching for movie where criminals are punished with aging
I'm trying to find the name of this movie.
The description:   

If anyone commits a crime and is found guilty, instead of serving
  time, they get aged for that amount of time.  No one is sent to
  prison. Convicts just lose that amount of life time. So, if someone
  commits a crime at the age of 21 and gets a 50 year sentence, he/she
  is simply aged up to 71.


I think this has been done a few times. Is it "In Time"?

People don't age in In Time. Everyone's appearance is frozen at something like 21 years old. You lose life span instead.

More details (like approximate year, country\language and specific scenes) might help narrow it down.

This one matches your description 30 Years to Life Original title "Nightworld: 30 Years to Life"
Storyline

In the near future, instead of being sent to prison criminals are aged
  for the number of years the system feels is adequate to the crime they
  committed. Vincent Dawson is a 15 year old, whose late father was a
  musician who didn't exactly make it and died tragically. Vinnie hopes
  to be a musician too but his step-father is not very supportive, and
  when they have a violent argument, his step-father is killed and he is
  the prime suspect and evidence is found against him. He is sentenced
  to be aged 30 years. Now, as a 15 year old trapped in a 45 year old
  body, he sets to prove his innocence and hopefully the procedure could
  be reversed.

Additional info :
Nightworld : 30 years to Life is a 1998 television film.
Wikipedia entry tells us :

In a futuristic society where prison has been abolished, a 15 year old
  is punished for a murder he didn't commit by being subject to a
  process that ages him thirty years. As an older man he sets out to
  find the real killer.

So, this does seems like a good match.

Similar question & answer here (though the answer was never approved).

@Walt oh thank you so much it was slowly driving me nuts...    I believe nightworld is it.....
